# Facebook login - URL blocked

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, oauth, laravel-socialite

I have an option for users to sign via Facebook. I'm using Socialite package. Everything works fine on local server, but in production I am getting an error which says that URL is blocked. I know that URL needs to be assigned in Facebook application, and I've entered (for example myapp.com/redirect). But when I click Login button, in browser I get an URI: `uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%` ... Where can I change this to myapp.com ? I've set an application to production mode in config/app.php, and also APP_URL to http://myapp.com... but the problem remains...

Comment: Maybe it's the server `hostname`?

Comment: The login dialog URL is created in your script. So if anything in there says `localhost`, then it is most likely that you are explicitly using that value in your code, and did not adapt it properly.